# Python and kdb integration

Tags: python, kdb

What are available tools/libraries to integrate `Python` with `kdb`?

Comment: I guess you found https://bitbucket.org/halotis/qpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found http://www.kx.com/a/k/connect/python/, along with http://bitbucket.org/halotis/qpy. I haven't used either.

Comment: I will add this one, and it even has some docs :) https://code.kx.com/trac/wiki/Contrib/PyQ#Releases

Comment: http://www.kx.com/a/k/connect/python/ is a link to older releases of pyk - Python for kdb (not kdb+!).  The latest (but still old) code for pyk can be found at http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/contrib/serpent.speak/trunk/K.

[PyQ](https://pyq.enlnt.com) is a successor to pyk and provides Python for kdb+.

Answer (score 9):

The timestored website has a [guide to the python apis for kdb](https://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api) complete with videos.
https://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api

To summarize your options:

1. [qPython](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython) - Newest API, supporting Python 2.7
2. [Dan Nugents Python Library](https://github.com/nugend/q) - Still maintained API for pulling data into Python <=v2.6 from a kdb server. Faster than qpy.
3. [qpy](https://bitbucket.org/halotis/qpy/overview) - Original API that was based on kx.com's java API. Slower than Dans but nicer formatting of tables when printed.
4. PyQ - Gone? - Brings Python and Q interpreters into the same process and allows code written in either of the languages to operate on the same data. Supports Python 2.7 and 3.x and all versions of kdb+.
5. PyKX - Commercial

Answer (score 1):

there's also Dan Nugent's https://github.com/DannoHung/q

also note that, as with [perl](http://kx.com/q/d/a/kdb+.htm#Client), sometimes the formatted export over the web socket is sufficient -- just GET `http://SERVER.example:PORT/FMT?QUERY`, where FMT is any of csv/txt/xml/xls (e.g. `http://localhost:5050/csv?table`)